# Liferay Build failed

Tags: liferay, portal

when i am trying to BUILD SERVICES for service.xml i am getting the following error.

```
  [java] D:\liferay-mvc\liferay-plugins-sdk-6.1.1-ce-ga2-20120731132656558\liferay-plugins-sdk-6.1.1\build-common-plugin.xml:169: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "D:\liferay-mvc\liferay-portal-tomcat-6.1.1-ce-ga2-20120731132656558\liferay-portal-6.1.1-ce-ga2\tomcat-7.0.27\jre1.6.0_20\win\bin\java.exe": CreateProcess error=87, The parameter is incorrect
     [java]     at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Java.fork(Java.java:798)
     [java]     at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Java.executeJava(Java.java:214)
     [java]     at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Java.executeJava(Java.java:135)
     [java]     at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Java.execute(Java.java:108)
     [java]     at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:291)
     [java]     at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)
     [java]     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
     [java]     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
     [java]     at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
     [java]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
     [java]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:392)
     [java]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:413)
     [java]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1399)
     [java]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1368)
     [java]     at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor.executeTargets(DefaultExecutor.java:41)
     [java]     at org.eclipse.ant.internal.launching.remote.EclipseDefaultExecutor.executeTargets(EclipseDefaultExecutor.java:32)
     [java]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1251)
     [java]     at org.eclipse.ant.internal.launching.remote.InternalAntRunner.run(InternalAntRunner.java:424)
     [java]     at org.eclipse.ant.internal.launching.remote.InternalAntRunner.main(InternalAntRunner.java:138)
     [java] Caused by: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "D:\liferay-mvc\liferay-portal-tomcat-6.1.1-ce-ga2-20120731132656558\liferay-portal-6.1.1-ce-ga2\tomcat-7.0.27\jre1.6.0_20\win\bin\java.exe": CreateProcess error=87, The parameter is incorrect
     [java]     at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:460)
     [java]     at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:593)
     [java]     at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Execute$Java13CommandLauncher.exec(Execute.java:862)
     [java]     at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Execute.launch(Execute.java:481)
     [java]     at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Execute.execute(Execute.java:495)
     [java]     at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Java.fork(Java.java:791)
     [java]     ... 18 more
     [java] Caused by: java.io.IOException: CreateProcess error=87, The parameter is incorrect
     [java]     at java.lang.ProcessImpl.create(Native Method)
     [java]     at java.lang.ProcessImpl.<init>(ProcessImpl.java:81)
     [java]     at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:30)
     [java]     at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:453)
     [java]     ... 23 more
     [java] Java Result: -1
     [echo] ${service.test.output}
    [mkdir] Created dir: D:\liferay-mvc\liferay-plugins-sdk-6.1.1-ce-ga2-20120731132656558\liferay-plugins-sdk-6.1.1\portlets\library-portlet\docroot\WEB-INF\service-classes
compile-java:
      [zip] Warning: skipping zip archive D:\liferay-mvc\liferay-plugins-sdk-6.1.1-ce-ga2-20120731132656558\liferay-plugins-sdk-6.1.1\portlets\library-portlet\docroot\WEB-INF\lib\library-portlet-service.jar because no files were included.
   [delete] Deleting directory D:\liferay-mvc\liferay-plugins-sdk-6.1.1-ce-ga2-20120731132656558\liferay-plugins-sdk-6.1.1\portlets\library-portlet\docroot\WEB-INF\service-classes
BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 638 milliseconds
```

Comment: that's sad. And the question is?

Comment: how to over come that error that i am getting when i am doing the folloing steps liferay SDK->build services

Comment: I don't see any steps

Comment: My question is why this error is coming??????

Answer (score 1):

You're running into [IDE-678](https://issues.liferay.com/browse/IDE-678). The ticket links to a [forum post](http://www.liferay.com/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/15392035) that describes a workaround. Alternatively - as it's a path length issue - it might work to just move your plugins-sdk to a directory with a shorter name - e.g. `D:/liferay/sdk`